# How to use other key combination to replace ⌘W?

Tags: keyboard, iterm

I am using a small mechanical keyboard on which if I press a special function key and key 'W', it means 'up'

I use [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) as my console app. From time to time I use 'up' to recall past commands.

Unfortunately this function key is next to the ⌘ key. So sometimes I miss the special function key, and pressed ⌘W accidentally. It closes an active tab of `iTerm2' instead of going back in command history.

Is there any way I can use some key combination to replace and disable ⌘W in order to close a tab?

Comment: I don't know iTerm, but if the items you need to switch have actual menu commands, this will work - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175053/disable-q-for-a-specific-application

Comment: Wow! Didn't know about this feature before! It's very powerful. Your suggestion is a life-saver! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped:) I'll flag this as a duplicate, so in future anyone searching for either issue will be able to find the answer.